# How to identify duplicate images in a ReactJs project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a simple ReactJS project with 100+ components. Many of those components have `images` folder with images needed for that particular component.

Is there a way to easily identify all the duplicate icons/images present across components?

Comment: may you can make a python script, to traverse all the files in the component folder and compare the names of icons/images

Comment: Names could be different. Also, image extension could also be different.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't specific to React or Webpack. The easiest thing is to use cli tools made for the general purpose of finding duplicate files.

On Linux/MacOS, install [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) with your package manager of choice, then you can run

```bash
fdupes -r /path/to/folder
```

To have an interactive menu to delete these duplicate files, add the `-d` command. This won't automatically delete them, this just likes you select individual files and ranges of files to delete interactively.

On Windows, you can run this command in Powershell

```
# find duplicate files
# Kenward Bradley 2016-12-29
# http://kenwardtown.com/2016/12/29/find-duplicate-files-with-powershell/
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-FileHash | Group-Object -Property Hash | Where-Object Count -GT 1 | foreach {$_.Group | select Path, Hash}
```

Make sure your current working directory is where you want to be, otherwise you can use `-Path your\path\here`.

This Windows version just lists out the files, it doesn't delete them. There exists [some scripts](https://sid-500.com/2020/04/26/find-duplicate-files-with-powershell/) that automatically delete, but I would advise against that.

Example output, where `bar.txt == foo.txt`, `fox.txt == the.txt`, and `baz.txt` is different from both sets.

[image]